# Local editing in an Ext grid

Tags: extjs, grid

I am using [Ext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_%28JavaScript_library%29)'s `Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel` to create a grid and using array-store with local data to populate rows in grid. When I edit the values in grid, they show a small red triangle at top-left, and also the store data is not updated.

So how can I edit local data in EditorGridPanel?

I see a similar problem in Ext [Editor Grid Example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html), though that example also set the URL, see image below.

[image]

Solution: As I just needed to save changes locally I just did the following.

```
settingsGrid.on('afteredit', function(evt){
settingsGrid.store.commitChanges()
})
```

It fixes the problem and all user edited data is happily updated in the local store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The red triangle on the top left denotes that the value has been changed. When user change the data in the grid, the store does keep track of the modifications.

If you need to save the modifications, you will have to send the updated data back to server side. You can make use of `DataWriter` for this.. [refer to this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/writer/writer.html)!

**Update:**  If you don't plan to move the updates to server, you can use:

- getModifiedRecords() - to get all the modified records.
- commitChanges() - commit the changes.
- rejectModifiedRecords() - reject all changes on store.

These methods are operations on store on the client side. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: But that is the question, I don't want to send anything to server, I want to do local editing, just want to keep my data in store, can you show me example of a DataWrite which will keep data on client side?

Comment: ok, but what happens after the user edit? shouldn't he commit the changes back to the source? you can use commitChanges() or if you need an array of all changes use getModifiedRecords()

Comment: He doesn't need to use any of the methods you specified. The example I linked to simply creates a store from XML data and initializes a EditorGridPanel with that data. The same thing can be done with an ArrayStore.

Comment: it is temp data which user needs to change and preview on client side only, so I don't need to send it to server

Answer (score 1):

The [Editor Grid Example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html) makes use of an `EditorGridPanel` without making trips to the server (take a look at the edit-grid.js link on that page). You need to post your code to help us debug your situation.

Make sure that you don't have `restful: true` defined on your ArrayStore. I would also recommend using the `data` property rather than `url` if you want to keep things local.

Comment: the example does set `url: 'plants.xml'` and when i edit that grid I do see red corners (modified) in firefox, see my edit in question